# Top Down Recursive method isn't working and not sure how to fix it. Java

Tags: java, algorithm, mergesort, recursive-datastructures

I have a homework problem for my "Data Structure and Algorithm class" - Implement a Top Down Recursive Merge Sort in Java. Demonstrate that your sort works by generating a random sequence of 100 numbers, printing them in their raw unsorted form, sorting them, and then printing them out in their sorted order.

And i did a little bit of coding and it seems to be right but i am getting an error and can't figure out what i did wrong.

```
class RecursiveMergeSort
{
void TopDownMergeSort(int[] mainArray, int[] copyArray) // mainArray, copyArray, int n
{
    CopyArray(mainArray, copyArray);
    Split(copyArray, 0, 100, mainArray);
}

private void Split(int[] copyArray, int start, int end, int[] mainArray)
{
    if(end - start < 2)
    {
        return;
    }
    int middle = (end + start) / 2;
    Split(mainArray, start, middle, copyArray);
    Split(mainArray, start, end, copyArray);
    CombineArray(copyArray, start, middle, end, mainArray);
}

private void CombineArray(int[] mainArray, int start, int middle, int end, int[] copyArray)
{
    int s = start; //a
    int m = middle; //b

    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        if(s < middle && (m >= end || mainArray[s] <= mainArray[m]))
        {
            copyArray[i] = mainArray[s];
            s = s + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            copyArray[i] = mainArray [m];
                    m = m + 1;
        }
    }

}

private void CopyArray(int[] mainArray, int[] copyArray)
{
    System.arraycopy(mainArray, 0, copyArray, 0, 100);
}

void UnsortedArray(int[] unsortedArray)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < unsortedArray.length; i++)
    {
        int random = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        unsortedArray[i] = random;
        System.out.println("\t" + i + unsortedArray[i]);
    }
}

void SortedArray(int[] unsortedArray)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < unsortedArray.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("\t: " + i + unsortedArray[i]);
    }
}
}
```

And here is Driver:

```
public class RecursiveDriver
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] randomNumbers = new int[100];
    int[] sorted = new int[100];


    RecursiveMergeSort test = new RecursiveMergeSort();
    System.out.println("Unsorted Array:");
    test.UnsortedArray(randomNumbers);
    System.out.println("Sorted Array");
    test.TopDownMergeSort(randomNumbers, sorted);
    test.SortedArray(randomNumbers);
}
}
```

This is what I am expecting:

Unsorted List: 100 61 8 76 51 89 30 63 11 1 47 74 85 63 80 45 18 34 74 25 8 90 61 44 25 2 40 100 47 1 72 24 86 80 87 75 46 85 14 30 43 31 27 48 96 96 26 20 44 1 67 1 30 35 87 78 18 46 37 31 6 61 62 92 71 45 6 10 12 38 96 14 22 83 96 31 65 74 58 47 87 65 28 61 91 73 3 92 87 22 68 0 9 18 13 89 36 8 35 44

Sorted List: 0 1 1 1 1 2 3 6 6 8 8 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 14 18 18 18 20 22 22 24 25 25 26 27 28 30 30 30 31 31 31 34 35 35 36 37 38 40 43 44 44 44 45 45 46 46 47 47 47 48 51 58 61 61 61 61 62 63 63 65 65 67 68 71 72 73 74 74 74 75 76 78 80 80 83 85 85 86 87

And that’s the outcome I get when I run my script:
But i am getting:

Unsorted Array:
035 
175 
270 
392 
436
And it keeps going until I get an error:
Sorted Array Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError at RecursiveMergeSort.Split(RecursiveMergeSort.java:16) at RecursiveMergeSort.Split(RecursiveMergeSort.java:17) 
It seems like it has something to do with line 16/17 but i am not completely sure how to fix it. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I'd start by looking at this line: `Split(mainArray, start, end, copyArray);` . You're just passing the same parameters back into your recursive method call, which will result in infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int middle = (end + start) / 2;
    Split(mainArray, start, middle, copyArray);
    Split(mainArray, start, end, copyArray);
    CombineArray(copyArray, start, middle, end, mainArray);
```

Should be

```
    int middle = (end + start) / 2;
    Split(mainArray, start, middle, copyArray);
    Split(mainArray, middle, end, copyArray);
    CombineArray(copyArray, start, middle, end, mainArray);
```

You were super close, just the start index of the second recursive call should be from the middle index to the end, not the start all the way to the end again (resulting in the stack overflow error)

On a side note - you should rename your methods to comply with the standard, ex: they start with a lower-case letter such as:

```
private void combineArray(int[] mainArray, int start, int middle, int end, int[] copyArray)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Bergis! Also, weird part is i should be getting random numbers from 0 to 100 but i get from 0 to 9999. This is kind of complicated for me but i am working on it haha.

Comment: No problem at all! Feel free to mark this as 'Answered' if you feel your question is complete. :)

Comment: Bergis, not sure if you saw my message in the comment since i had to edit it, could you take a look why i am going up to 9999 instead of a 100?

Comment: Totally, you actually do not have numbers up to 9999 in your arrays. The culprit is in these two lines of code that you are printing to your console:

`System.out.println("\t" + i + unsortedArray[i]);`

Notice how you are concatenating the `i-th` index value from the `for` loop in the string to be outputted to the console? Remove that so you are just printing this:
`System.out.println("\t" + unsortedArray[i]);`

That shows you the actual values in the array, which will be between 0 to 100.

Comment: Also, another note on this question... I do not believe your current method to get a random number **between** 0 and 100 **inclusive** works. It generates a random number between 1 and 100 **inclusive**. There is a better way using Random, it needs to be imported and can be used as such:

`Random ran = new Random();`
`int num = ran.nextInt(101);`

if you want to generate a num between 1, 100 though; your code works just fine.